# how best to express 'in case of...'

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, idiom

can 'in case of + noun' be translated as si + genitive, e.g. 'si ignis' (in case of fire)? or is a verbal clause (i.e. si forte + subjunctive) more idiomatic? thanks!

Comment: How about _caso ignis_ or _caso igne_?

Comment: @BenKovitz Isn't *casus* fourth rather than second declension? That's certainly a word worth exploring in this context.

Comment: @BenKovitz No, these are something about a torch falling somewhere :-) the 4th declension *cāsus* refers to an unforeseen event, a misfortune that "befalls", and there's no way to use it in provisions; poetically it's used for 'an allowing event, opportunity' on a couple of *occasions.*

Comment: Oops, _cāsū_! But probably still wrong, for the reasons @Unbrutal_Russian gave.

Comment: @Unbrutal_Russian Would ''igne accidente'' or ''igne contingente'' work?

Comment: @Figulus *accidēns* and *contingēns* are philosophical terms translating Greek (see L&S for details), 'the non-substantial, extraneous circumstance' and 'the contingent, present or absent by chance'. They have no use in the ordinary language. Even in technical use the PHI corpus only has [1 suitable occurrence](https://latin.packhum.org/concordance?q=contingente%23) ('accidental, extrajudicial servitude'). Though there are a few more in folks like Boetius. *contingēns* also means 'a composite body'. —And it's not *igne* (see my answer).

Answer (score 3):

No, a *sī*-clause cannot be nominal, it needs a predicate; in absence of one it reads just like 'if a fire' in English, i.e. as a elliptic list item with the same verb as before understood. The only possible verbless use is as in *sī quisquam, ille* 'if anyone then surely him'.

'in case of X' has two major uses:

- as a provision for a likely event, you basically want to translate 'if there's fire', which is easy: ***sī incendium fuerit;*** likewise, 'in case a tree is felled by lightning = if a tree falls after being hit by lightning (call your local spirit guide for further instructions)' ***sī arbōs** fulgure icta **ceciderit***. The perfect tense expresses the sense of **definiteness & punctuality** which in English distinguishes 'in case of' from a simple 'if'; the latter expressed in Latin as *sī incendium **erit,** sī arbōs **cadat.***

  - notice that *ignis* refers to the light-emitting effect of combustion, and not to an area or property that's on fire.

  A couple of ready-translated examples from [Livy's Loeb](https://www.loebclassics.com/view/livy-history_rome_26/1943/pb_LCL367.35.xml), indicating ongoing states (the narration is present but the events are in the past):

  > Senātus magistrātibus in forō praestō est, **sī quid cōnsulere velint** [...] aliī offerunt sē, **sī quō ūsus operae sit.** ('The senate awaited the magistrates in the Forum, *in case they wished its advice about anything* [...] others volunteered, *in case of any need of their services.*'
- as a casual precaution for an unlikely event ('you never know'), that's when you need *forte* 'perchance': ***sī forte incendium erit,** aliā perveniēmus* 'in case there's a fire (in our way), we'll get there by another route'; *Lūcium **sī forte vidēbis** salvēre jubētō* 'in case you happen to see Bob, pass him my greetings'.

When listing **alternatives,** these are introduced with *sīve~seu* 'else if': *sī A, B; sīve C, D...*

With **negation,** *sī* becomes *nī* 'if not' and *sīve* becomes *nīve~neu* 'and if not' (often spelled NEI and NEIVE). This one smacks of legalese and archaic language, to be used on occasion:

> **id nī fit,** mēcum pignus sī quis volt datō ('*if this isn't the case,* let anyone who wants bet against me', Plautus)

Comment: very clear, thanks!

Comment: I just came across this construction in Petrarch, but I can't figure out why it's imperfect subjunctive, unless it's iterative? Petrarch is asking a friend to send out people to search for classical manuscripts: Etruriam perquirant, religiosorum armaria evolvant ceterorumque studiosorum hominum, si quid usquam emergeret leniende dicam an irritande siti mee ydoneum.

Comment: @Kingshorsey This seems in line with the medieval/renaissance use of the impf. as a reservation and politeness marker, basically a downstep in the degree of certainty compared with the present one. It may be more common when subordinated to another subjunctive, as if to better distinguish the two levels syntactically. I don't find many examples after some random searches (really just one), but I remember remarking on this on several occasions (also when asked about it while reading with others); cf. [this article](https://www.njrs.dk/7_2011/06_plesner_horster_perotti_subjunctive.pdf).

Comment: @humanissime Scytha. optimum et subtile responsum, ut semper.

Comment: @Kingshorsey: May we have the ref. on Petrarch? Thank you.

Comment: @tony:- LETTERA (III, 18)      A GIOVANNI ANCHISEO. See http://www.cassiciaco.it/navigazione/scriptorium/testi%20medioevo/petrarca/familiares/lettera_III_18.html

Comment: @Unbrutal_Russian: Literally, "si quo (should it be 'quis' from plural 'alii') usus operae sit" = "if from whom experience may be of help"; what is the function of "quid" in "si quid consulere velint". I keep wanting to write, "quem"; "if they want to consult 'them'/ it/ the Senate"--masculine, singular, accusative relative pronoun. Obviously, it isn't "quem"!

Comment: @tony *quō* is directional, 'if there's need of their service anywhere', you can even delete the *sī* to get *offerunt sē quō...*.  Why not *ubi?* Because when volunteering you ask 'where to', not 'where is it'. *quid* is naturally the object of the verb, 'to get advice on anything'. Additionaly *sī quid* is used as an internal accusative even with intransitive verbs, comparable to 'somewhat' in English but more often equivalent to 'a bit, for some time, any etc.'